# Insert Text to Word Range

Tags: c#, ms-word

I use interop.Word to create a Word document programmatically.
In the document I have a particular range which I would like to insert text to.

When I google it I see that the way to do this is :

```
 range.Text=" Whatever...";
```

but I have no "Text" property for the range object.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you getting the range?

Comment: @Andrei `Range range=wordApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures[i].Range;` for example, and I would like to give a caption before "Table of Figures". Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: How do you know that there is no such property? You have a compilation error?

Comment: @Andrei, When I do range. I have no "Text" in the drop down list

Comment: That does not necessary mean that there is no such property, it might be just intellisense not working. Try writing this code anyway, compile, run and see what happens

Comment: @Andrei Thanks, I've tried it. Instead of inserting the text before the ToF, it replaces it! What have I to do?

Comment: If you want to edit text before - you most likely need to work with other element that either precedes ToF or wraps it

Comment: @Andrei Could you please guide me a little more? I do not understand you properly

Comment: Ok, I'll try to come up with an answer soon

Comment: @Andrei Thanks in advance! For sure I'll accept it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the orignal question - this is just an intellisense bug, there is such property in the `Range` class.

For the problem from comments that

```
Range range=wordApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures[i].Range;
range.Text=" Whatever...";
```

replaces the ToF instead of prepending it with text. If you just want to set a header of the table, you can use `Caption`:

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures[i].Caption = "Header text";
```

If however you need some text preceeding the ToF - check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311310/insert-text-before-a-list-using-word-interop) which is discussing similar case, but for the list instead of Table of Figures.

Another way to set caption is to select range you need and call `InsertCaption`:

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures[i].Range.Select();
wordApp.Selection.InsertCaption("Whatever");
```

Note that `InsertCaption` accepts various args of various types, make sure to try different.

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for your detailed answer. When I use the code above the tof is not updated even though I have update it!

Comment: @Andrey, Thanks for notification! I tried the new idea with different values but program fails! What exact ones work fine?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert text at a range position, you can use [Range.InsertBefore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.insertbefore(v=office.14).aspx).

```
Range range=wordApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures[i].Range;
range.InsertBefore("My Text here. ");
```